# Write to file from a method with variables from Main

Tags: java, filewriter

I have variables that are  from my main, and I want to use a private (or public doesn't really matter I am keeping them in the same class) method to write them to a text file. I have accomplished writing them to a file from within the main... I just cant figure out how to call variables from the main into my  writeToFile() method.  Below is what I have attempted but Im not sure how to incorporate the two.

```
 //This portion is what I had in my main method that wrote the info to a file successfully 

     //Write to File
             String fileName = "order.txt";
             try{
                 PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
                 writer.println("Thank you for ordering from Diamond Cards");
                 writer.println("Name: " + customerName);
                 writer.println("Returning Customer: " + customerReturn );
                 writer.println("Phone: " + custNumber);
                 writer.println("Card Type: " + customerType);
                 writer.println("Card Color: " + customerColor);
                 writer.println("Card Coating: " + customerCoat);
                 writer.println("Item Amount: " + numItems);
                 writer.println("Total Cost: " + fmt1.format(totalCostMsg));
                 writer.flush();
                 writer.close();
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Receipt has been printed"); 
             } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
                        {e.printStackTrace();
                        System.exit(0) ;         
                        }    
             }


// This is where I try to create a method to do the file writing.... not sure how to proceed..


   public static void writeToFile() {
            try{
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("order.text"); //File name to be created
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (fw);          // Prints to the file that was created
         //text to be printed to file

        // close the writer     
                pw.close();
        // catch errors     
                } catch (IOException e) {
                out.println("Error!");
                }
            }
```

I also need to figure out how to make a separate method to read the file back in but I think I can engineer that if I can just figure this part out.

Comment: Simply add the parameters that you need in `writeToFile()` so that you can pass them in...

Comment: as such?     writeToFile(customerName, numItems, .....blah)   ?

Answer (score 1):

You want to define `writeToFile` with arguments, and pass them in from `main`:

```
   // Add additional arguments.
   public static void writeToFile(String fileName, String customerName, ...){
       FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName);
       writer.println("Thank you for ordering from Diamond Cards");
             writer.println("Name: " + customerName);
       // Use additional arguments.
   }
```

From main:

```
writeToFile(fileName, customerName, ...);
```

I agree with Mr. Polywhirl though. It will be cleaner if you create a wrapping object, although I am not so sure you even need `getters` and `setters` for this purpose.

```
// The types are all String because you did not mention the types in your
// question.
class Customer {
    public String Name;
    public String Return;
    public String Number;
    public String Type;
    public String Color;
    public String Coat;
    public Customer String(String Name, String Return, String Number, String Type, String Color, String Coat) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Return = Return;
        this.Number = Number;
        this.Type = Type;
        this.Color = Color;
        this.Coat = Coat;

    }
}
```

You could then do the following in `main`:

```
Customer c = new Customer(customerName, customerReturn, customerNumber, customerType, customerColor, customerCoat);
```

Inside the `writeToFile` method with the same signature as Mr. Polywhirl's answer, you could directly do `customer.Name`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass objects around by adding parameters to your methods. If you need to reference something in another class or method, just add more parameters.

I suggest that you create a Customer object so that you can pass it around as a single entity instead a couple dozen parameters.

You can try something like this:

```
public class FileWriteExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "order.txt";
        Customer customer; // Customer object...
        int itemCount;
        float totalCost;
        try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
            writeToFile(writer, customer, itemCount, totalCost);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Receipt has been printed");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void writeToFile(PrintWriter writer, Customer customer,
            int itemCount, float totalCost) {
        Card card = customer.getCard();
        try {
            writer.println("Thank you for ordering from Diamond Cards");
            writer.println("Name: " + customer.getName());
            writer.println("Returning Customer: " + customer.getReturn());
            writer.println("Phone: " + customer.getPhone());
            writer.println("Card Type: " + card.getType());
            writer.println("Card Color: " + card.getColor());
            writer.println("Card Coating: " + card.getCoating());
            writer.println("Item Amount: " + itemCount);
            writer.println("Total Cost: " + fmt1.format(totalCost));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be some fields that are not required or unavailable, like contact number, etc. Rather than sending a long list to write to file, consider using a Builder Pattern as suggested by Joshua Bloch in Effective Java.